# Format hard drive with ntfs in order to switch back to Windows

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, format

I want to switch back to Windows, so I booted from a Windows installation DVD, but I can't format my hard drive with the setup. How to format my hard drive as ntfs so I can switch back to Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because Windows uses a different filesystem than Ubuntu.

1. Boot into the Ubuntu Live CD
2. Open gParted (should be already installed)
3. Shrink the current Ubuntu partition and create an empty NTFS partition (30 gigabytes should be enough) that will receive windows
4. Using gParted, add a `boot` flag to the new partition
5. Apply your changes
6. Next boot into the Windows installer and you should be able to install Windows on the new NTFS partition that you just created.
7. After you have installed Windows, boot into Windows, [delete](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/remove-partition-windows-10-free.html) the Ubuntu partition, and add the freed up space to your Windows partition.

Thats it!

Comment: Hey, i found that partitioning it from linux doesn’t work , because windows uses a different partition system , so i completely wiped it on linux and partitioned it on the windows setup, thank you so much for your help, i wouldn’t have know where to start without you :)